# dijkstra's algorithm using adjacency matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, dijkstra

I am currently trying to create a program for Dijkstras algorithm. I a having trouble understanding what how to create the graph for the algorithm.

I am having trouble implementing this into a graph.

I want to create a function called

```
add_edge(G, Source, destination, weight);
```

I want to use this function to create my graph so I can later create a random graph. For example I would do this:

```
add_edge(G,1,2,3);
add_edge(G,1,6,5);
add_edge(G,2,3,7);
etc.
```

The first thing I would think to do is create G but I am unsure of how to do this. I am thinking to make another function called construct which would be equal to G such as:

```
G = construct(Vertices);
```

I am just unsure of how to construct this.

If someone could help me understand these two functions it would be great help!

Comment: IMO the matrix that you have shown can be seen as a graph as it has all the information in it.

Comment: Im sorry but I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: The matrix itself represents the entire graph where matrix[i][j] is the cost of directed edge from node i to node j.

Comment: make a two-d array, say int weights[6][6], and fill the array with the values from your table. If an entry has doesn't have an edge, use 0 or  -1 to represent that.

Comment: Yes I created that to represent the desired result. But I am trying to use the add_edge function to create the graph so I can later create a random graph. Ill edit my question to show what I mean.

Comment: add_edge(int src, int dst, int weight) would just be weights[src][dst] = weight; With the proper array bounds check of course.

Comment: So I would not need to use G?

Comment: I think I may have been confusing myself. I was thinking G = (V,E). V being vertices and E being edges. But would this only be for linked lists?

Comment: Please look at some of the answers provided - my own and @james-hostick's answer are both good methods for handling something like a weighted graph; in fact, I myself did this assignment last semester for a Discrete Mathematics course. There are two methods of implementing this (that inherently make sense without convolution): 1. a `2-d array (matrix)` or `structs`. Depending on your implementation, you may not even need to have a `G`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to make an nx x ny array of ints:

```
int **construct(int nx, int ny) {
    int **a = malloc(nx * sizeof(*a));
    for(int i = 0; i != ny; i++) {
        a[i] = calloc(ny, sizeof(int));
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is `G`...? Is `G` your `graph`? Or is `G` the `matrix` which you use to represent your graph? It would make the most sense to have something like the following (pseudo):

```
// This is your graph, represented by a 2-d array.
// i would be your source (vertex)
// j would be your destination (vertex)
// graph[i][j] would be the weight of the edge between those two points

int graph[][];

// Then you could add an edge to your graph with the following:

add_edge(graph, source, destination, weight) {
  graph[source][destination] = weight;
}

// A specific example would be:

add_edge(graph, 10, 11, 5)
```

Though you need to know: 2-d arrays in C are actually an array of pointers of type `p`.

so `int **graph;`

See Charlie's answer for how to (specifically) create a `matrix of ints`.

Comment: @user081608 What I mean is... what is the **structure** of `G`? Is `G` a `matrix of ints` (`2-d array`)? Or is G some kind of `list of Vertices`, where you have `struct Vertex`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to make a graph using a matrix, go with the aforementioned answers. Otherwise if you are going to build it using structs, perhaps something like this could get you started

```
typedef struct VertexT *VertexP;
struct VertexT
{
     /*the value of the current Vertex*/
     int vertex;

     /*pointer to a list of edges, each value being an end point since this
     is a directed graph*/
     EdgeP edges;

     /*pointer to a list of weights, each weight corresponding to each edge
     thus there should be an equal number of items in both lists or there
     is an error condition*/
     WeightP weights;
}

typedef struct GraphT *GraphP;
struct GraphT
{
     /*pointer to a list of vertices in the graph, should contain exactly
     n vertices, where n is the number of nodes in the graph*/
     VertexP vertices;
}
```

This is by no means the only way to do this, but I wanted to provide a struct method as an alternative to using strictly matrices. If it is a sparse graph, using lists can optimize space complexity over going with a matrix. Hope that helps get you started.

Note: I used the typedefs because I find that using VertexP or GraphP is easier to read and understand than struct *VertexT and struct *GraphT, it's stylistic more than anything.

Just saw your edits regarding the addEdge() function. If you were going with my representation, you could look at the pseudocode as something like this:

```
addEdge(GraphP g, int source, int dest, int weight)
     test for g being null:
          if true, create a graph or throw exception
          if false, continue
     search for source in VertexP list:
          if true, 
               search for dest in edges
                    if true report error
                    if false add new edge and weight to list on the source VertexP
          if false, create new VertexP with source, dest, weight and add to list
```

Comment: I forgot the most critical part of the VertexT, the identifier of the Vertex itself. Added from the initial post lines 4-5 in the code block to indicate this.

Comment: Excuse edits, studying for a test simultaneously while doing this, edges and weights should be structs themselves containing int values and a pointer to the next edge and weight in the list, so they should be typed as structs themselves, not as ints.

Comment: I actually really like this answer, much more so than a `matrix`-based solution. In my opinion, it's best to try to solve problems at the highest level of abstraction - in this case creating a `struct Vertex` that has properties is a good way to model how they can be represented in a `Graph`. Personally an object-oriented or prototyping style is more appropriate and more understandable than say a *matrix of ints*. Though both have their strong points - `matrix` in this case being more efficient, but `structs` being more  readable as they "translate to English" better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look into this type of representation

Comment: Thank you, although matrices have their uses as well. I like my representation for a sparse graph, but if you are going to do something where it is a mostly full graph, like maze building for example, matrices can be more efficient.

Comment: When you say create a graph would that be the construct function I was saying up above?

Comment: Pretty much. You would have a createGraph() that allocates memory and initializes to an empty graph. Then start adding edges with addEdge()